# Restriction on ARM linux phys_to_virt/virt_to_phys runtime patching

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel, arm

I understand ARM linux supports runtime patching of phys_to_virt and virt_to_phys. 
http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2011-January/037089.html

This enables the kernel image to support different physical base address without requiring recompilation.

I have a 2GB board with physical memory from 0x8000_0000 to 0xFFFF_FFFF. 
I see the following results when using the board:

Kernel Load Physical Address: 0xC0008000 - OK (Kernel Boots up)

Kernel Load Physical Address: 0xC8008000 - OK (Kernel Boots up)

Kernel Load Physical Address: 0xD0008000 - NOT OK (Hang in starting kernel)

Kernel Load Physical Address: 0xE0008000 - NOT OK (Hang in starting kernel)

My linux kernel cmd line bootargs mem=512M.

I would like to understand the restriction on valid load address of the kernel.
This is documented at :  [www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/memory.txt](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/memory.txt)

I am unable to copy-paste it here as the formatting gets messed up.

Document mentions not following the restriction will result in a kernel that does not boot which is what I am facing but  I am unable to understand the restriction on kernel start address.

I dont use highmem.

Is the restriction Linux start address + lowmem_size should be <= ff000000 - VMALLOC_SIZE.

Comment: What method are you using to load the kernel?

Comment: @unixsmurf (Corrected typo) The kernel is loaded via tftp.The documentation says if kernel is loaded at physical address 0x8000_8000 in RAM, it will be relocated to 0x8000_0000.

Comment: yes, but how are you running tftp? You provide no information about what platform you are using, so I can't even begin to guess what bootloader you have and what interaction issues could be had with that.